# In which Stars Wars book(s) can I find more about Jango Fett and his selection as the Clone Army template?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I want to explore more about Jango Fett with emphasis on his selection process as the Clone Army template. In which book (from *Legends* canon of course) can I find that?

Comment: There's a humourous (non-canon, even in Legends) account of Fett's selection in *Star Ware Tales* 24, called [Fett Club](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fett_Club)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story of how Jango Fett was selected for the Grand Army of the Republic was covered in the video game [*Star Wars: Bounty Hunter*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Bounty_Hunter). The description from Wookieepedia:

> *Star Wars: Bounty Hunter* preludes Episode II *Attack of the Clones* and tells the story of how and why Jango Fett became the template for the clones of the Grand Army of the Republic.
>
> When the leader of the Bando Gora cult, Komari Vosa, became a threat to Palpatine's plans, he instructed Dooku, his apprentice, to eliminate her. He also charged Dooku with the task of finding a suitable person to become the template for the future clone army. Dooku decided that he could accomplish both of these tasks by putting a bounty on Vosa, and he only invited the very best to take up the challenge. These included two former Mandalorians: Jango Fett and Montross.

Since the story was covered in the video game I don't think there is a novel which covers the story. As indicated in the description, [Komari Vosa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Komari_Vosa) is central to Jango's selection as clone template. Wookieepedia has a short list of [appearances](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Komari_Vosa#Appearances) for her, and her main appearances are in the aforementioned video game and and the novel [*Maul: Lockdown*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maul:_Lockdown). However, *Maul: Lockdown* takes place before her death and does not mention Jango Fett. The closest I can find to a *book* which explains how Jango came to be the clone template is the comic book series [*Jango Fett: Open Seasons*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jango_Fett:_Open_Seasons). The description from Wookieepedia (emphasis mine):

> *Jango Fett: Open Seasons* is a comic series that delves into the dark past of Jango Fett. Most notably, the series reveals how Fett became a Mandalorian warrior, and **how he was recruited by Count Dooku. It is a tie-in to *Star Wars: Bounty Hunter* video game**. It is a virtual version of the real comic.

[image]